# Issue with latest version of kinetic js

Tags: html, kineticjs

I have code sample [code](http://jsfiddle.net/akhiyadav1/LmM4K/1/#run) which will run perfectly when i am using kinetic-v3.10.1.min.js other than that any latest versions of kinetic.js raising me an script error

```
TypeError: this.attrs.container is undefined
[Break On This Error]   
this.attrs.container.appendChild(this.content);
```

Please help me out in this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log

What you really have to do is go through this change log and look at what you have in your code vs what's in the newer versions.

My guess, from looking at your code, is that Kinetic.Shape is no longer supporting drawing of images, that's what Kinetic.Image is for.